# Gradle Multi-Project Setup Layout - Multiple Dependencies

Tags: gradle, multi-module

I'm converting an existing java multimodule project to gradle. The dependencies are a bit complicated - in short, I have something along these lines:

```
Root project MainProject  
+--- Project ':P1'  
|    \--- Project ':P1:P2'  
\--- Project ':utilProject'
```

So, my mainProject depends on P1, which in turn depends on P2, and a utilProject.
The thing is, **both P1 and P2 also depend on the utilProject**.

In the build.gradle for each of these projects was just compiling the ':utilProject' (the project is always in the root, and the projects for the main one look as I wrote above):

```
dependencies {  
   compile project(':utilProject')  
   // compile some other dependencies   
}
```

P1 and P2 are fine (compiling without errors), however the main project won't compile. I've tried changing the code in utilProject around, and found that while the utilProject itself does compile the latest changes, the the main project is blind to them.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

/// Update - July 20th 2014

Forgot to mention the MainProject is an eclipse plugin, and so we use the wuff plugin to compile (though I'm not sure it's relevant).

Seems like there is no need for P2 - P1 won't compile either (previously it just didn't use that bit of updated code. My bad).

Also, while I wasn't able to reproduce, I was able to find a workaround - adding the latest utilProject.jar to the dependency list seems to do the trick. I'm not sure why it's necessary... any ideas? Note that I did have to add the P1.jar to the MainProject and so on to make things work, which seems to indicate something's wrong with the dependency list, but all the projects on that list compile just fine.

Comment: Can You prepare a minimal working example and place in ot GitHub e.g.? Just to have a try, because it seems difficult to reproduce just from description.